# Suppose a, b, n ∈ N. Use the Euclidean algorithm to prove that gcd(na, nb) = n gcd(a, b)

Tags: elementary-number-theory, proof-verification, formal-proofs

I had this for homework before, and I wrote:

*There exists s,t, that are elements of integers, such that gcd(a,b) = sa + tb, so ngcd(a,b) = n(sa + tb) = s(na) + t(nb)*

but I got it wrong.

How do I write a rigorous formal proof to answer this?

Comment: You didn't calculate (or mention) gcd(na, nb) at all...

Comment: can you guide me? I know the euclidean algorithm, but not sure how the n would carry over, or what to do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The existence of integers $x$ and $y$ such that $ax + by = c$ only guarantees that $\gcd(a, b)$ divides $c$. Thus, you only showed that $\gcd(an, bn)$ divides $n \gcd(a, b)$. One way to get the converse would be to note that $n \gcd(a, b)$ divides both $na$ and $nb$ (because $\gcd(a,b)$ divides both $a$ and $b$) so, because $\gcd$ is the largest common divisor, $\gcd(an, bn) \ge n \gcd(a, b)$, so they are equal.

But this line of proof doesn't use the Euclidean algorithm at all.
To use the Euclidean algorithm, 
write 
$$a = q_1 b + r_1,\quad 0 < r_1 < b$$
$$b = q_2 r_1 + r_2,\quad 0 < r_2 < r_1$$
$$r_1 = q_3 r_2 + r_3,\quad 0 < r_3 < r_2$$
$$\vdots$$
$$\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad r_{k-2} = q_k r_{k-1} + r_k,\quad 0 < r_k = \gcd(a,b) < r_{k-1}$$
$$r_{k-1} = q_{k+1} r_k + r_{k+1},\quad r_{k+1} = 0.\quad\quad$$
This shows the Euclidean algorithm proceeding through $(k+1)$ steps, where at the $(k+1)$th step we find the remainder to be zero, so the previous step's remainder is the $\gcd$ of $a$ and $b$.
**Now multiply all the steps and inequalities by $n$.** The equality $r_{k+1} = 0$ implies $n r_{k+1} = 0$, so the previous step's remainder, $n r_k = n\gcd(a,b)$, is the $\gcd$ of $an$ and $bn$.

Comment: so to answer the question, do I simply write out the euclidean algorithm, then multiply it by n, and since "The equality rk+1=0 implies nrk+1=0, so the previous step's remainder, nrk=ngcd(a,b), is the gcd of an and bn." ?

Comment: Well, you should also explain that "if we perform the Euclidean algorithm on $an$ and $bn$, then at step $i$ we will have $R_{i-2} = Q_i R_{i-1}+R_i$ where $0< R_i< R_{i-1}$ if $i \le K$ and $R_{K+1} = 0$ (note I am letting $an = R_{-1}$ and $bn = R_0$). But if we multiply the above table by $n$, then we see that, at every step, $nr_{i-2}=q_i nr_{i-1}+nr_i$ with $0 \le nr_i < nr_{i-1}$. Therefore we have $R_{i-2} = Q_i R_{i-1} + R_i = q_i nr_{i-1} + nr_i$ for all $i\le k+1$; by the uniqueness of the division algorithm, $R_i=n r_i$ for all $i\le k+1$. Finally, $R_{k+1}=nr_{k+1}=0$ so $K=k$.